# None value for paho_mqtt::create_options::CreateOptionsBuilder persistance

Tags: rust, mqtt, paho

The documentation for [CreateOptionsBuilder method.persistence](https://docs.rs/paho-mqtt/latest/paho_mqtt/create_options/struct.CreateOptionsBuilder.html#method.persistence) indicates that setting this value as `None` will improve the performance, but ending up with a less reliable system.

Could someone elaborate on this? Please. Under which circumstances should I consider setting this to `None`?

Comment: Does the [documentation of the `PersistenceType`](https://docs.rs/paho-mqtt/latest/paho_mqtt/create_options/enum.PersistenceType.html) clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Eclipse Paho MQTT Rust Client Library](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.rust) is a "safe wrapper around the Paho C Library". The [persistence](https://docs.rs/paho-mqtt/latest/paho_mqtt/create_options/struct.CreateOptionsBuilder.html#method.persistence) options are [mapped to values](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.rust/blob/master/src/async_client.rs#L163) accepted by the C library with `None` becoming `MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE`. The [docs for the C client](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/_m_q_t_t_async_8h.html#a5462c4618d0a229116db5fbadacf95d2) provide a more detailed explanation of the options:

> persistence_type   The type of persistence to be used by the client:
> MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE: Use in-memory persistence. If the device or system on which the client is running fails or is switched off, the current state of any in-flight messages is lost and some messages may not be delivered even at QoS1 and QoS2.
> MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_DEFAULT: Use the default (file system-based) persistence mechanism. Status about in-flight messages is held in persistent storage and provides some protection against message loss in the case of unexpected failure.
> MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_USER: Use an application-specific persistence implementation. Using this type of persistence gives control of the persistence mechanism to the application. The application has to implement the MQTTClient_persistence interface.

The upshot is that calling `persistence(None)` means that messages will be held in memory rather than being written to disk (assuming QOS1/2). This has the potential to improve performance (writing to disk can be expensive) but, because the info is only stored in memory, messages may be lost if your application shuts down without completing delivery.

A quick example might help (simplifying things a little); lets say you publish a message with QOS=1 and a network issue means that the broker does not receive it. When the connection is re-established (failed delivery will generally mean the connection will drop) the client will [resend the message](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901238) (because it has not processed an acknowledgment from the broker). With the default persistence (disk) the message will be retransmitted even if the failure was due to a power outage that affected the server your app was running on (obviously this only happens when power is restored and your app restarts); that message would be lost if you had called `persistence(None)`.

The appropriate setting is going to depend upon [your needs](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901232) and other options may have an impact (e.g. if [Clean Start](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901039)/[CleanSession](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Ref362965194) is true then there unlikely to be any benefit to persisting to disk).

Answer (score 0):

When you don't care if all messages are received. E.g. when using only QOS 0 messages